# Can electrical in a pergola be ran to pool lights breaker to run ceiling fan and outlet?

Tags: lighting, ceiling-fan, outdoor, pool

We recently had an aluminum pergola installed with an electrical outlet and would like to install a ceiling fan.

The electrical in the pergola, which is not GFCI, was ran to the pool lights breaker in our pool panel that is GFCI. Both pool and pergola were professionally installed and city inspected & approved.

While getting quotes for the ceiling fan install, I was told that you cannot run electrical for a fan or the outlet to the pool breaker because it’s against electric code.

Can you please advise if this is true?

(*It’s ran to the pool lights breaker, not pool pump breaker*).

Comment: Will this ceiling fan have a light kit on it?

Comment: Also, can you get whoever's giving you the quote to give you a citation to which section of the NEC they believe it violates?

Comment: Yes, it will have a light kit. The electrician who I spoke with is coming out tomorrow to have an in person look but I’ve inquired about this here and with our pool contractor and neither have encountered this issue in the past.

Comment: Unless the lights specify being on a dedicated circuit, I don't get the violation.

Comment: Is the structure over the pool? Within 5’ I could see issues there , when you say the pergola power is not GFCI protected but goes to the lights breaker that is protected this sounds unusual is the circuit tapped at the pergola then goes on to a GFCI the pergola receptacle would require GFCI not sure how that would have passed.